# Counting relay circuit

Tags: circuit-design, relay, counter

I'm looking at making a circuit that activates a 12 V momentary relay a settable number of times with a settable wait time between each activation.

At the moment I'm using a Jaycar KA1732 kit, but it's not quite what I need.

How easy would it be to modify this kit to meet my requirements or would I be better off programming an Arduino to output what I need?

Comment: use a microcontroller

Comment: `how easy would it be?` ... `would I be better off?` ... your questions ask for opinions ... that is not allowed here, because any answer is valid ... please add a clear, answerable question that is on topic here

Comment: Is *settable number of times*, \$N\$, where \$0\le N\le \infty\$? Or is there a smaller range? Same question for the *settable wait time*...

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: @Callum We can't guess about what qualifies as "*meet my requirements*." Working crystal balls are hard to come by. So you will have to spell it out. And unless someone just happens to have the unit you are talking about and has completely explored its design beforehand, I doubt a suggested modification is likely to be forthcoming.

Comment: ok dratted editing has a time out lol

Comment: I know my way around a soldering iron , but circuit design is not my area of knowledge, so asking if this would be something a novice could do.

Comment: as for the second clarification, settable counst would be between 1-500 and settable wait times between each count( relay activation) would be between 1-60 seconds.

Comment: @Callum Sure, you can do it. I designed and built a working CPU. And before I started I really didn't know anything much except some basic boolean logic math and a tiny bit of DC electronics. After a year's time I got it working, too! So yes, a novice can do whatever they set their minds to doing. I'm not suggesting this project is that hard. I'm just pointing out that you can do it if you set your mind to it and apply yourself long enough. Perhaps, even, by modifying the unit you have. (No idea about that, though.) Or perhaps by finding a better solution.

Comment: @Callum You are looking for a count range of about three orders of magnitude and a time range of about two orders of magnitude. This may very well be the right time to learn how to program a microcontroller.... But it can be done with logic devices. Just it will be a nice piece of work and once you see it you may very well run back to getting a micro and learning to program it... We can't know how you will react to seeing it done without an MCU. Did you plan on entering the two figures by setting binary switches? Or what else did you have in mind for setting these two values?

Comment: @Callum Just looked at the picture of the unit you mentioned. It uses a [CD4020](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4020b.pdf?ts=1706791013359&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4020B). So the answer is ***NO***, you will not be able to make simple modifications to the board to get where you are headed.

Comment: Thank you for the input, Ill look at the MCU idea and see how I go.

Comment: From where you are starting, I would suggest something like an Arduino Nano (original or clone). There's an Arduino SE site. You only need the unit and a USB cable and some free-to-download software.

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment im using a Jaycar KA1732 kit but its not quite what I
> need: **settable counts between 1-500 and settable wait times between each relay activation of 1-60 seconds**.

That device has the following schematic (which I pulled from [this link archiving the March 1991 copy of *Electronics Australia*](https://archive.org/details/EA1991/EA%201991-03%20March/page/n92/mode/1up)):

[image]

The author(s) suggest the idea of using a rotary switch to match up the CD4020 outputs with the BJT base.

> How easy would it be to modify this kit to meet my requirements

Not easy. The schematic has a 555 timer, which may be useful. But it also uses a CD4020, which isn't readily usable for your needs. And finally it includes a simple circuit to activate the relay -- which may be useful. But the CD4020 provides the core functionality which differs fundamentally from your own needs.

> or would I be better off programming an arduino to out put what i
> need?

An Arduino (or Raspberry Pi) would likely be over-kill. However, there's lots of educational and library support for them. And learning to program them is about as easy as it gets. Also, it's quite likely that you can find an add-on board (*shield*) with relays that you can directly use, too. So this may be the fastest way to get what you need done.

More, you likely can get all manner of nice ways to enter your 1-500 and 1-60 numbers -- even up to and including a keyboard and a display like a PC has. So it can be pretty fancy.

You could also consider the idea of modifying the board you have so that it uses a microcontroller to replace the 555 and CD4020, while keeping the relay and its driver circuit. But here you would be deeper into the programming weeds, so to speak, and you would still need to come up with some way of setting your 1-500 and 1-60 numbers.

In summary, I think there are at least these three directions. (1) Develop your own complete logic system (without writing any software or using an MCU or Arduino or Raspberry Pi) and replace the CD4020 with that logic system; and (2) Assemble an appropriate set of Arduino or Raspberry Pi hardware and learn to write your own software and use existing library code to get the job done; and (3) Consider details needed to add a tiny MCU to the existing board (also replacing the CD4020) and learn to write embedded software for it.

In all cases you will have to come up with a way to specify the 1-500 and 1-60 numbers you want to use.